# How to show only rows in a html table according to select option on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my table, I want to show only those rows which is selected in the drop down.

For example:

1. By selecting on the 'All' option, table should display all the rows.
2. By selecting on the '2017' option, table should display only those rows which contains "2017" in the 2nd column.
3. By selecting on the '2018' option, table should display only those rows which contains "2018" in the 2nd column.

I want the rows to be display on the moment the year is selected in the drop-down.

```html
  <select name="year">
     <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select> 
  
  <br><br>
<table border="1">
<tr><td width="5%"> 1 </td><td width="30%">2017</td></tr> <br>
<tr><td> 2 </td><td>2018</td>
<tr><td> 3 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr><td> 4 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr><td> 5 </td><td>2018</td>
<tr><td> 6 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr><td> 7 </td><td>2018</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could use the change event of the dropdown to know when to hide the rows

Comment: Add classes to each tr tag that you can toggle the visibility of using Javascript

Comment: Or try to use the Datatables library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#year").on('click', function(){
    var yr = $(this).val();
    $("table tr").each(function(index){
      var val = $(":nth-child(2)", this).html();
      if(yr === 'All') {
        $(this).show();
      } else if(val == yr) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  })
;

  $("#year").trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="year" name="year">
     <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
  </select> 
  
  <br><br>
<table border="1">
<tr><td width="5%"> 1 </td><td width="30%">2017</td></tr> <br>
<tr><td> 2 </td><td>2018</td>
<tr><td> 3 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr><td> 4 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr><td> 5 </td><td>2018</td>
<tr><td> 6 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr><td> 7 </td><td>2018</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only one thing is not in place, i.e. if I use Selected option it still display all the data. <option value="2018" selected>2018</option>

Comment: For that, you can trigger click event in ready function. Added that in above code, please see if it works.

Comment: Please, help me to make this work in mobile browser. I have press twice in Mobile

Answer (score 0):

Without adding classes and ID's, you could do as shown:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // When the select box is changed
  $("select[name=year]").on("change",function(){
     // if the value isn't the default
    if($(this).val() != "All"){
        // loop each row
      $("table tr").each(function(){
       // if the second <td> value isnt the same as the select box
       if( $("td:eq(1)", this).text() != $("select[name=year]").val() ){
          $(this).hide();   // Hide it
       }else{
          $(this).show();  // Else show it
       }

      });    
     // And if the user selects "All", then show all the rows again
     }else{

            $("table tr").show();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and neat way in my opinion is adding a class attribute in whichever you want to group.

```
<tr class="y2018" ><td> 2 </td><td>2018</td>
<tr class="y2017" ><td> 3 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr class="y2017" ><td> 4 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr class="y2018"><td> 5 </td><td>2018</td>
```

you could also add more classes to group whatever you want.

```
<tr class="y2018 orange" ><td> 2 </td><td>2018</td>
<tr class="y2017 orange" ><td> 3 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr class="y2017 apple" ><td> 4 </td><td>2017</td>
<tr class="y2018 apple"><td> 5 </td><td>2018</td>
```

Then you could do

```
$(".y2018").hide();
```

or e.g

```
$(".orange").css({"background-color":"#000"});
```

Previously you have you get the select value when the user change select component.

```
$("select").change(function(){

var value = $("select").val();

if(value == 2017){
//do somethig like
$(".y2018").hide();
}

});
```